# How can I time a loop iteration in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops, profile

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
for (0..10000) {
    $my_array[$_] = `some external program`;
}
```

And I want to time how long each iteration takes and how long the whole furshlugginer thing takes.

What's the best way to do this inside Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Time::HiRes 'gettimeofday', 'tv_interval';

my $start = [ gettimeofday() ];

for (0..10000) {
    my $iteration_start = [ gettimeofday() ];
    $my_array[$_] = `some external program`;
    $elapsed_secs[$_] = tv_interval($iteration_start);
}

my $total_secs = tv_interval($start);
```

gettimeofday may not be available on all platforms.  The returned seconds will be a floating point number.

Answer (score 6):

Use Benchmark from the core modules: http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html

Basically something like this:

```
use Benchmark;
$t0 = Benchmark->new;
$my_array[$_] = `some external program`;
$t1 = Benchmark->new;
$td = timediff($t1, $t0);
print "the code took:",timestr($td),"\n";
```

and to test multiple iterations try:

```
$t = timeit(10000, '... code...');
print "10000 loops of code took:", timestr($t), "\n";
```